# How would I mathematically represent that, in an Index, the subsequent number will be less than the preceding number?

Tags: logic

What is the equation where position 1 is less than position 0, etc, to Infiniti.

```
Index
0, 1,000,000
1, 900,000
2, 800,000
3, 700,000
4, 600,000
5, 500,000
6, 400,000
7, 300,000
8, 200,000
9, 100,000
10, 10,000
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Really?  On what planet?

Comment: @user2661923 Nothing new here; pretty much every boilerplate comment made by people hiding anonymously behind the Community bot is garbage. Best to just ignore them.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Your strategy, which has been implemented by most reviewers, has failed to end the garbage.  My strategy, should, in the long run, pay off, if my strategy attracts other reviewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you label each number as, say $x_n$, then you're looking for: $\quad x_{n+1}<x_n$ for every $n$ $\in\mathbb{N}$.